# ExtJS Issue with boolean data and grid column list filter as well as Ext.Data.Store

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJS 6 (although from what I can tell it applies up to version 7.4 as well) and I have a grid with a booleancolumn xtype.  For that boolean column I wanted to use the filter list option.  Yes I know there is a boolean filter option however I don't like how it works using a radio button.  I wanted to be able to select the Yes or No with checkboxes, however I found that only the option with true as the value worked.  Here is my column config:

```
{
header: 'Active'
, dataIndex: 'inactive'
, xtype: 'booleancolumn'
, trueText: 'No'
, falseText: 'Yes'
, filter:{
            type: 'list',
            options: [[true,"No"],[false, "Yes"]]
        }
}
```

This didn't work when excluding the 'options' property and letting it get the data from the store either by the way.  After looking through the code I discovered that it takes the 'options' config and creates its own Ext.Data.Store using that as the data.  See here as a simple example that can be run that will get the same issue:

```
var teststore =  new Ext.data.Store({
        fields: [
            'id',
            'text'
        ],
        data: [[true,"No"],[false, "Yes"]]
    });
```

The problem is that the 'false' boolean value is changed and is replaced with a dynamically created generic id.  I discovered the issue lays in the constructor for 'Ext.data.Model' for the following line:

```
if (!(me.id = id = data[idProperty]) && id !== 0) {
```

If that line evaluates to true it will replace the id with the generated one.  To fix this I just added ' ***&& id !== false***' to the end of the if statement and this fixed the issue.

I have not tested this fully, however the logic seems sound and it looks like the same type of issue occurred with the value of '0' hence the **' && id !==0'**. Since we are directed here from the sencha forums I wanted to bring this up in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my post already has the answer I will post a better way to do it other than directly changing the Ext code file (whether this is the proper way I may be wrong).  Instead, you can create a new js file that will need to be included in your application (you can name it ext-overrides.js).  In the new js file you need only type:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Model, {
    constructor: function(data, session) {
        .....
    }
}
```

You would then copy the constructor function code from your version of the ExtJS code in where the '.....' is (if perchance the constructor function arguments are different you would have to update those as well) and just add the suggested change I made above in the 'question'.  A search of the Extjs code for **Ext.define('Ext.data.Model'** should get you there easily and then just scroll to the constructor function.